# Make trend change chart with ggplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I just read an article [here](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-swing-states/)

Does anybody knows if/how we can produce a similar chart like this in R with ggplot package or other libraries? This is such a cool visualisation

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could achieve a very similar look with ggplot. I think this gets you pretty close:

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(value = c(0, 5, -3, -1, 1, 2.5),
                 year  = 500:505 * 4)

label <- paste0("Miami-Dade County,\n",
                "home to a large share\n",
                "of Florida's Cuban\n",
                "population, went from\n",
                "backing Clinton by 30\n",
                "points to supporting\n",
                "Biden by just 7 points")

arrow <- data.frame(year = 2016 + 4 * sin(seq(-0.2, pi/2, 0.04)),
                    value = 5 + 8 * cos(seq(-0.2, pi/2, 0.04)))
```

**Plot code**

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(year, value)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess", span = 0.82,
              size = 3, color = "#846a9a") +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 8, aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_label(aes(x = 2010.5, y = 4, label = label),
            check_overlap = TRUE, hjust = 0, family = "Arial",
            label.size = NA, size = 5.5) +
  geom_path(data = arrow, 
            arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(10, "points"))) + 
  ggtitle("Florida") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#796fae", high = "#9b6197", guide = guide_none()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-25, 25), breaks = 0:4 * 10 - 20, position = "right",
                     labels = c("D+20", "D+10", "0", "R+10", "R+20")) +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = df$year) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18, margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10),
                            family = 'Arial Narrow'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "gray95"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 24, hjust = 0.5, face = 2,
                                  margin = margin(30, 30, 30, 30)),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "gray50"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(0, 80, 20, 80),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "white"),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(20, "points"))
```

[image]